# Automatic Linkification for network files in PHP

Tags: php, regex, linkify

I'm trying to automatically detect links in user-submitted text and dynamically generate links.  I've found that this works well for "normal" URLs.

`$pattern = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
return preg_replace($pattern, "<a href=\"\\0\" rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\">\\0</a>", $str);`

Is there a way this could be expanded to cover UNC or mapped network drives such as `\\ComputerName\SharedFolder\File.txt` or `Z:\Dir\File.txt`?

I'm not necessarily looking for a perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious non perfect solution is to just have three patterns and check each one in turn.  (So, look for \\ and [A-Z]:\ and grab everything up to the first whitespace.)

Comment: You can probably do the second two in one go by checking for something like /(([A-Z]:|\\)\\S+)\s/, but I can't see a way of doing it all in one pattern that wouldn't be both unreadable and a pain to debug.